# How to install debug flash player 11.1 on 64-bit

Tags: firefox, flash

I had Firefox working with the debug flash player that I downloaded from [Adobe Flash Player Support Center](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) following the instructions on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1300563. However, today, an automatic update came into my Ubuntu 11.10, which upgraded the flash player to 11.1.102.62 (a non-debug version).

When I copied the debug flash player again per instructions in the ubuntuforms link, flash does not work anymore.

I guess that the problem might be related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/+bug/870835

If they are now using the 64-bit flash plugin, it would make sense that the 32-bit debug flash player (There is no 64-bit debug flash player for the moment) does not work.

Is there anybody who knows how to work around this so I get the i386 plugin back with the nspluginwrapper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the workaround:

First install the 'nspluginwrapper':

```
sudo apt-get install nspluginwrapper
```

or Using Software Center [image: Install nspluginwrapper via the software center]

Then copy the debug player to the correct location:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/
```

Next, call `nspluginwrapper`:

```
sudo nspluginwrapper -i /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
```

Answer (score 4):

Ugh.  Not enough rep to comment yet...

For anyone following these instructions who gets the following error:

nspluginwrapper: no appropriate viewer found for /usr/lib/flashplugin-debugger/libflashplayer.so

Make sure you also `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Anybody trying to run 32 bit software on a 64 install probably already has them, but I've been trying to keep my machine clean, and didn't have them yet.

Perhaps one of the other two duplicate answers can update to include ia32-libs.

Also, an upvote so I can comment instead of this extra post would be nice.
Thnx.

Comment: Still getting an error "nspluginwrapper: no appropriate viewer found for /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so"

Comment: Did you try following the install instructions of the accepted answer?  If so, did nspluginwrapper return success or do nothing?

Please post more details of what you've tried so we can help you further.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, it worked OK on my box. To summarize this was my process:

1. Install flashplugin-installer package (not adobe-flashplugin)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
   ```

   or using Software Center [image: Install via the software center]
2. Run this (as in previous post):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nspluginwrapper
   sudo cp ~/Downloads/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/
   sudo nspluginwrapper -i /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
   ```