# FlashBuilder 4 Linux -- Debugger disconnects after a while

Tags: flash, eclipse, debugging

I am running ubuntu 12.04 64Bit, I have installed eclipse via the software center,  [FlashBuilder for Linux](http://code.google.com/p/fb4linux/) and the [flash debugger plugin](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) as decribed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104723/how-to-install-debug-flash-player-11-1-on-64-bit). everything is working fine accept that the debugg session is just disconnected after a while. No errors, nothing, just end. [Here is the .log file](http://pastebin.com/7UfBEWRG) of the project. I am using flash player 11.2. What could that be? Any Ideas how to fix this? Greetings...

Answer (score 0):

here's a trick i found useful,

set your debug configuration to launch about:blank and then as its waiting to attach to a debugger, connect to it with the flash context menu by right clicking -> Debugger -> Connect.

http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2007/12/4/Connecting-Flex-3-to-a-running-Debugger-session